# Can the sums of the first few terms of two geometric progressions with different prime common ratios (start from $1$) be equal?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, geometric-series

Consider two geometric progressions with different prime ratios, which both start from $1$. The question is, can the sum of the first $m$ terms of one progression equal to the sum of the first $n$ terms of the other progression?

The sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric progression starting from $1$ can be written as $\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$, when the ratio is $p$. Suppose the two prime numbers are $p$ and $q$. The question can be transformed into whether $$\frac{p^{m+1}-1}{p-1}=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}$$ have solutions or not. But I don't know how to deal with it and have no idea about other possible methods to think of the question.

Please give me some ideas.

Comment: If the sums are the same starting from $1$, then the sums are the same starting from the second term in each progression, as you merely subtract $1$ from each sum. This gives you one sum explicitly divisible by $p$ and another sum explicitly divisible by $q$.

Comment: $1+2+4+8+16=31=1+5+25$

Comment: Isn't this a famous equation with only one known solution ?

Comment: The [Goormaghtigh Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goormaghtigh_conjecture) would tell us that that example is the only one with a prime base, and that if you drop the primaility on the base, that $8191$ is the only other example (in bases $2$ and $90$).

Comment: @lulu thanks for telling me The Goormaghtigh Conjecture!